# kotlin multiplatform for ios framework with private api : __NSCFBoolean

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, iphone-privateapi

Use kmm's cross-platform capabilities to create a new kmm app, compile and run iosApp to generate shared.framework, but shared.framework contains private api: __NSCFBoolean. Since the appStore review does not allow the use of private api, it may cause the app to fail to be put on the shelf.
The current kotlin version is 1.8.21.

Question: How to remove this private API or which version removes it to solve this problem?

[image]

Remove private api: __NSCFBoolean

Comment: Already registered https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-62091